# How to Forward an authorative zone in BIND between internal and public clients

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns, dns-zone

I have a dns server authorative for my public records and my internal records , I want to forward a zone in my internal dns server so internal clients can access certain records without using the public dns. Yet still having issues forwarding the zone. Both DNS servers work fine but how can I use for my internal clients to use the internal dns and still resolve public domain names. For some reason I have read older posts and still does not work. Machines are on centos9 bind latest version. Any help is appreciated.

Internal DNS:

```
zone "jack.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/jack.com";
    allow-query { x; };

};

zone "public.com" IN   {
 type forward;
 forward only;
 forwarders { public-dns;};
};
```

Public DNS:

```
options {

    allow-recursion { any; };
};

zone "public.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/public.com";
    allow-query { any; };
};
```

public.com:

```
$TTL    3H
@       IN      SOA     dns.public.com. hostmaster.public.com. (
                2023100904 ; Serial (increment this when making changes)
                8H         ; Refresh
                2H         ; Retry
                1W         ; Expire
                1D         ; Negative Cache TTL
);

@       IN      NS      dns.public.com.
@       IN      A       192.168.1.15
dns.public.com.    IN      A       192.168.1.15

store.public.com.   IN      A       10.1.1.23 
online.public.com.  IN      A       10.1.1.24
```